# How to check given start date and end date period is between available start date and available end date (database) in MySQL with some conditions

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

- Given start date and end date not between available start date and end date
- Given start date and end date is not in range of available start date and available and date `((given start date <= available start date or given start date is >= available end date) and (given end date <= available start date and given end date >= available end date))`

**Solution**

select * from abc where ((startDate <= @enddate and endDate >=  @startdate) or (startDate < @startdate and endDate > @startdate and startDate < @enddate and endDate < @enddate));

Any other solution ?

For Example :

database :

id: 1
start date: 21-1-2017
end date: 23-2-2017

condation 1:
apply start date : 22-1-2017
apply end date : 22-1-2017

ans : 
start date: 21-1-2017
end date: 23-2-2017

condation 2:
apply start date : 20-1-2017
apply end date : 23-1-2017

ans : 
start date: 21-1-2017
end date: 23-2-2017

condation 3:
apply start date: 22-1-2017
apply end date : 24-1-2017

ans : 
start date: 21-1-2017
end date: 23-2-2017

condation 4: 
apply start date : 20-1-2017
apply end date: 24-1-2017

ans : 
start date: 21-1-2017
end date: 23-2-2017

condation 5: 
apply start date: 18-1-2017
apply end date: 20-1-2017

ans:
null

condation 6: 
apply start date: 24-1-2017
apply end date : 25-1-2017

ans:
null

condation 1: 
apply start date: 28-1-2017
apply end date : 28-1-2017

ans:
null

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: you use 'between' clause?

Comment: Note that Event A can be said to overlap Event B if Event A starts before Event B ends, and ends after Event B starts. And no. You DON'T use BETWEEN clause

Comment: As long as startdate and enddate are indexed then there is no optimization needed (given current post context)